# Hibernate HQL Syntax

Tags: hibernate, hql

I've searched endlessly online for the definitions of various HQL expressions but haven't been able to find anything. Could somebody provide definitions and explanations for the following?:

> in
>
> elements
>
> member of
>
> collections